# correct format for Swift NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, swift, datetime, timezone, nsdateformatter

I have this time format **2016-09-06T12:44:00.118Z**

What is the correct format for NSDateformatter? With below format it doesn't seems to be calculating the correct time.

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
```

This last 118Z part of the date string is probably the time zone. So What dateFormat could be used here instead .SSSZ ?

I couldn't find a way to construct a proper formatter string with the help of this,

http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
```

Comment: it decodes the correct date and time with this format. But not sure if it's picking up the correct time zone. Can you explain what SSS and 'Z' does?

Comment: SSS is fractional second & Z is UTC Timezone

Comment: Don't forget to set the `timeZone` to GMT and the `locale` to `en_US_POSIX`.

Comment: @Rob thanks! I was having problem getting the correct date until I set `timeZone` and `locale`